# How to know when the DOM is ready again after a insertion in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I'm working on a application with Backbone.js.

When I'm switching of page, the global view of the current page is replaced with the view of the new page. Inside that view, I have a typical "render" function which replace the body html by the new template.

My problem is, after changing the html, so the DOM, how can I execute a function when the DOM is ready again ?

I have to use it because I need to scroll to an element and just executing my scrollTo() function after the render() don't work ($(myElement).offset().top always return me 0).

Here is my code :

```
module.exports = BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
        $('html, body').scrollTop(this.$("#toScroll").offset().top);
    },
    template: require('./templates/home'),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your view's `el` is in the DOM and your `#toScroll` is inside the view's `el`, then `#toScroll` will be in the DOM as soon as you say this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template());
```

However, the HTML won't be rendered until after the browser gets control again (i.e. after your view has done all its work). The elements inside your `el` won't have any size or position information until the browser has rendered all of it (unless of course you're positioning and sizing everything by hand). The sequence of events goes like this:

1. `v = new View`.
2. `initialize` is called and that calls `render`.
3. `render` sets up everything in the DOM.
4. The view calls `this.$('#toScroll').offset()` and gets zeros.
5. The view tries to `scrollTop` to zero.
6. The browser gets control back.
7. The browser renders everything, this process computes the positions and offsets you want.

You just need to get **4** and **5** to happen after **7**.

An easy way to do that is by putting your position/size dependent things inside a [`_.defer`](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) callback:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.render();
    var _this = this;
    _(function() {
        $('html, body').scrollTop(_this.$("#toScroll").offset().top);
    }).defer();
}
```

You can also use a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a delay of zero but `_.defer` makes your intent clearer.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tWSBE/